# What is this 200 GB VMWare file?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, vmware

I recently found this file (`VM-W-7-Pro-x86-Sandbox-SANITIZED-2021-01-24-200g(B)(2cpu-3gig)`) in my Windows laptop. It's in a `VM` folder on my `C` drive. It's taking up a ton of space on my computer, what is it?

(Hannu said "Try to add it as an earlier created VM, the name seems to indicate that it might work.", but not sure how to, it's a `file` file type.)

Answer (score 4):

It very much appears as if it could be a Snapshot file. A Snapshot is the original VM file with changes you have made. That is why they are so big. I also think more changes (more Snapshots) can make the file bigger.

Normally, you need to COMBINE the Snapshot with the original file to save the changes and remove the Snapshot. This can take time so be aware of that.

With the Snapshot tools (not Explorer) you can delete the Snapshot to remove it if you do want the changes.

Be sure to use the Snapshot tools to combine or delete the Snapshot. Do not use Windows Explorer to manage the files.

The VMware Snapshot tools are built into and part of the VMware App.

Also now, if you are unsure of what the file is (and it may be something different - we do not know for sure from here) and if you are sure you do not need it, you can delete it.  Take care, deleting files in the machine folder are usually not recoverable, so make sure you know you do not need it before deleting.

Comment: Does Snapshot come with Windows? or do I need to install it?

Comment: No. Snapshots are made by the VMware App in response to temporary changes you make for testing purposes.

Comment: Snapshot files are numbered.  I think that the 200 GB file is more likely to be the main virtual disk file.

Comment: Most main VM files have much simpler names and that is why this appears to be a snapshot. The name appears to come from the main filename

Comment: The main VM files are named after the VM.  If the user gave it a complicated name, the main files will have the same name.  Snapshot files are *always* numbered (e.g. suffixed with `-00001`).

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what the file type/extension is, but it's most likely the (base) virtual disk for your VM.

Do *NOT* delete it unless you want to render your VM useless.

Since it's a Windows VM, if the VM is powered off, with VMware Workstation Pro you can choose VM > Manage > Clean Up Disks to shrink the virtual disk to reclaim space on the host that's not actually being used by the guest OS.  However, you can do that only if your VM is using a *sparse* virtual disk, which means that the virtual disk (`.vmdk`) file is growable.  If your virtual disk is *preallocated*, then it has a fixed size (that you asked for when you created the VM), and it cannot be shrunk. (If your disk file is exactly 200 GB, it sounds like it's preallocated.)

If you want to convert the preallocated disk to a sparse one, you can use the  `vmware-vdiskmanager.exe` command-line tool (located in `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\VMware\VMware Workstation`) to convert it.  However, you will need at least 200 GB of free disk space on your host since the tool will create a new disk file before deleting the old one.

Or, if you no longer need to use that VM at all, then you also could just delete the entire VM.

Comment: The lack of specific information is one of the reasons this question should be clarified so three separate users don’t all come to three entirely different conclusions